# PowerApps DatePicker size

Tags: powerapp, datepicker

Is there a way to increase the size of the calendar popup when the Datepicker is opened/selected?

It seems a little small and can be difficult to select a specific date on smaller phone screens. The Height and Width parameters only affect the control size when it is closed (not selected).

[image: small calendar size...]

Thanks,

gpence

Comment: Small? Weird, on mine it fills most of the vertical space of the screen, and most users complain that it's too big.

Comment: I would say mine is about 30% of the vertical and 40% of the horizontal space, but I'm looking on a Galaxy 8 Note which has a decent sized screen.

Comment: Mine is 80% of my laptop screen (vertical). This in a new, empty app, both in the phone size as well as the tablet size.